# Can you crash the host system using a docker container?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, crash, operating-system, panic

If yes, is there anyway to prevent the crash by using a kernel designed to not crash. I would like to run docker image from strangers, would like to know if there is anyway i could get griefed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: System should never crash, so if there is a crash, there is an unexpected event, so... system programmers prefer to fix crashes, instead of adding a new layer to protect from crash (and such layer could also crash). Just monitor the machine and reboot if necessary (you can set to reboot in case of panic). Keep software up-to-date, and do not run strangers dockers if you are a sensible target

Comment: I want to create a service where i will have to use docker containers from the user. User can potentially grief the system by sending docker container that crashes host system.

From your comment you are implying there are no known ways of crashing host system using docker? If there is a way its bug and needs to be fixed? Please clarify.

I am web dev and never had to work with linux/windows api for system programming.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/ But about security: do not trust me or anyone in internet. You need to hire a security expert (with hand on also on docker). personally, I would go also to virtual machines (an additional "firewall"), maybe just few dockers on each VM. But the main risk (IMHO), it is a missconfiguration of your docker